# Newly configured fields of WIT's not showing up in existing TFS Project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, tfs

I am trying to do some configurations of TFS work items. I added couple of new fields in the `WIT` type `Bug`. Then I uploaded the Process template using Visual Studio. But I dont see the changes in my existing Projects. If I create a new Project based on template that I changed, the new fields do appear in the new Project's `Bug` work item type.

I tried restarting Visual Studio, Browser, cleared cache but no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you just uploaded a Process Template. The template is only used on creating new Projects as you mentioned correctly.

If you want to use the new fields in existing Teamprojects, you need to import the WIT Bug to those.
You can do this with the witadmin.exe in the Developer Command Prompt for  Visual Studio.

eg.

```
witadmin.exe importwitd /collection:http://[tfsserver]:[port]/tfs/[collectionname]/ /p:[projectname] /f:[c:\temp\bug.xml]
```

Replace the parameters in the braces []

Documentation to witadmin.exe can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd312129.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)